# Sort names of zipped files and write list to file

Tags: shell, unix

I tried to list the zipped files in sort order and transfer this to new file, but it does not work properly in shell script. Why my script is not working?

```
ls |grep gz|sort -t '.' -k 2,2n >filename;
```

Comment: Command looks fine. Can you please update on which shell you are using and the file contents when ran through scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any problem with your commands. But they do not seem the right way to do this, at least to me. These two ways I'm pasting I think are better. Try them out.

With only names :

```
find . -type f -name '*.html' 2>/dev/null -exec basename {} \;  | sort   > filename.txt
```

With full paths :

```
find . -type f -name '*.html' 2>/dev/null | sort   > filename.txt
```

You can also add the "-maxdepth 1" flag to search only on the current directory where you are running this, and not recursively within nested dirs :

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '*.html' 2>/dev/null | sort   > filename.txt
```

Hope this helps you :)